# C++ primer 5th edition: placement new

Tags: c++, placement-new

Hello I have this text from C++ primer 5th edition:

> Explicit Destructor Invocation:
>
> Just as placement `new` is analogous to using `allocate`, an explicit call to a destructor is analogous to calling `destroy`. We call a destructor the same way we call any other member function on an object or through a pointer or reference to an object:

- Is it a mistake: "Just as placement `new` is analogous to using `allocate`" Did he mean analogous to `construct` not `allocate`?

Comment: Certainly doesn't read the right way around.

Comment: Not listed in the errata, but the errata I can find  pretty damn old.

Comment: Assuming that this is talking about `std::allocator<>`, then yes, placement new is more analogous to `construct()`

Comment: 10 years later is the 5th ed up to date enough to be considered a top-flight C++ text? Anyone done a a read-through of the 6th edition yet?

Comment: Related (sadly): [Is there an up to date errata for C++ Primer 5th Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863252/is-there-an-up-to-date-errata-for-c-primer-5th-edition)